# I need to make the contents of a textbox ciphered into a different textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption

So what I'm trying to do is make a basic char replace cipher in WPF, but for some reason the result box won't update when I hit enter. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with my C# code below?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static string PassingEncrypt;
    public static string PassingDecrypt;
    string plainText;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string key = "=2/3E*45-`~6<>!,.7+8[]9|:0";
        plainText = EncryptBox.Text;
        string cipherText = Encrypt(plainText, key);
        string decryptedText = Decrypt(cipherText, key);

        EncryptResult.Text = cipherText;
        DecryptResult.Text = decryptedText;
    }

    private void EncryptBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.EncryptBox = sender as TextBox;
        plainText = EncryptBox.Text;
    }

    static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[plainText.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (plainText[i] == ' ')
            {
                chars[i] = ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                int j = plainText[i] - 97;
                chars[i] = key[j];
            }
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }

    static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string key)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[cipherText.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cipherText[i] == ' ')
            {
                chars[i] = ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                int j = key.IndexOf(cipherText[i]) - 97;
                chars[i] = (char)j;
            }
        }

        return new string(chars);
    }


}
```

If you can't find a problem with that, here is my xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="EncryptBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="0,81,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=" " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" TextChanged="EncryptBox_TextChanged"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="DecryptBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="269,81,-0.6,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=" " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="EncryptResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="0,238,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="DecryptResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="269,238,-0.6,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this handling the `TextChangedEvent` in code behind, but you really shouldn't. This is what `Converters` are made for, keeping your View clean with no code behind.

Binding `Text` of the `Encrypt-` and `DecriptBox` to the `Text` of its predecessor and letting the `Converters` do the work.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:EncryptConverter x:Key="EncryptConverter"/>
        <local:DecryptConverter x:Key="DecryptConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>Plain Text</Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="PlainBox" MaxLength="26"/>
        <Label>Encripted Text</Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="EncriptedBox" IsEnabled="False"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=PlainBox, Converter={StaticResource EncryptConverter}}"/>
        <Label>Decripted Text</Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="DecriptedBox" IsEnabled="False"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=EncriptedBox, Converter={StaticResource DecryptConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    // View with no code-behind
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    // From plain to encripted Text
    public class EncryptConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string plainText = (string)value;
            char[] chars = new char[plainText.Length];
            string key = "=2/3E*45-`~6<>!,.7+8[]9|:0";

            for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
            {
                if (plainText[i] == ' ')
                {
                    chars[i] = ' ';
                }
                else
                {
                    int j = plainText[i] - 97;
                    chars[i] = key[j];
                }
            }
            return new string(chars);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    // From encripted to plain Text
    public class DecryptConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string cipherText = (string)value;
            char[] chars = new char[cipherText.Length];
            string key = "=2/3E*45-`~6<>!,.7+8[]9|:0";

            for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.Length; i++)
            {
                if (cipherText[i] == ' ')
                {
                    chars[i] = ' ';
                }
                else
                {
                    int j = key.IndexOf(cipherText[i]) + 97;
                    chars[i] = (char)j;
                }
            }

            return new string(chars);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```